# Patent office statistics and reports for rejected Patent applications

Tags: patent-services

I periodically see announcements / articles that state X hundred thousand applications were filed in 20##, at the: USPTO, EPO, JPO, KIPO.... and company Y filled Z thousand.

I'm curious as to the success rates at the various Patent Offices, are there any official statistics on the number of final rejections in a given year, the number of final rejections by company?

Answer (score 1):

Most of Patent office releases such reports called annual reports.

for USPTO :-

[Statistics](http://www.uspto.gov/patents-application-process/patent-trial-and-appeal-board/statistics)

[General Patent Statistics Reports](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/ac/ido/oeip/taf/reports.htm)

For European Patent office:-

[European patents and patent applications - 2014 statistics](http://www.epo.org/about-us/annual-reports-statistics/statistics.html)

[Top Patentees](http://www.epo.org/about-us/annual-reports-statistics/statistics/patentees.html)

for JPO:-

[Japan patent statistics](http://www.jpo.go.jp/shiryou_e/toushin_e/kenkyukai_e/pdf/annual_report2014/part5.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, will have a proper dig but they appear to only give Applications and Grants in a period, not final rejections. If I were to simply subtract the grants from the applications, for a period I'd get the false impression that 3/4 of applications have been rejected in the period.

Comment: just a heads up does that include invalidated patents

Comment: That could also be an interesting one, in the light of Alice, the NET number of patents awarded in 2014 could be negative (Applications - (Rejections + Invalidations) ).